# SWFObject redirectUrl not functional with ExpressInstall

Tags: javascript, redirect, swfobject

How do you specify a redirect URL for the adobe flash express install? I'm using [swfobject 2.2](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), and while I thought `MMredirectURL` in the `flashvars` might be what I needed, this just doesn't work. I also tried setting `redirectUrl` in the `attributes` object before embedding the swf, but this doesn't work either.

What is the proper way to specify a redirect URL to go through after the Express Install occurs with swfobject 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea, but here's a workaround. Set a cookie before the user leaves the page, and if they come to the same page WITH that cookie, perform a manual redirect. It's ugly, but it works.